# tcolorbox and RTL script in polyglossia

Tags: tcolorbox, polyglossia

I want to use `tcolorbox` in my Arabic document with `polyglossia`.

I want to insist on RTL display, but somehow LTR keeps appearing.

In the MWE below:

1. The first displayed line (ordinary text) is correctly RTL.
2. The second displayed line (containing multiple `tcbox`) is incorrect;
3. The third displayed line (same as second, but with some arabic text beginning the line) is correct RTL.

How can I change the code for the second line to insist on RTL?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Scheherazade}
\setmainlanguage{arabic}
\begin{document}
\tcbset{nobeforeafter}
١ \hspace{1cm} ٢ \hspace{1cm}  ٣

\tcbox{١}  \tcbox{٢}  \tcbox{٣}

كلمة \tcbox{١}  \tcbox{٢}  \tcbox{٣}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Where is this Scheherazade font available? I am unsure whether this possible this way with `tcolorbox` at all

Comment: the font is unimportant.  you can use Times New Roman, or any arabic script font

Comment: Well, how should tcolorbox know that it should use RTL?

Comment: I presume that is the business of polyglossia and the 'setmainlanguage' command.  But I don't know.